# Labeling 3D plots surfaces with numbers in suitable coordinates

Tags: plotting

**Question**

My problem is related to labeling different surfaces of any 3D plot as shown below on a plot of `Sin[x]Cos[y]`. How can I label any surface by different numbers `1 .. 4` enclosed in circles and attached to the surface?
I know I must use of `Graphics3D` but I am not able to place the labels in the suitable points on the surface.

[image]

**Details**

The real problem which I want to address is how to show two different plots with labels.

```
Show[
  plot1, 
  Graphics3D[{Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.007], Dashed], Line @ line1}]];
```

I want to merge the two graphics (a line and a plot) with `plot1`, which is a plot that has been created by `Listplot3D`

Comment: @m_goldberg, thank you for editing my question, edited one presents better the main aim.

Comment: Your circled numbers are not "attached to the surface."  Please draw precisely what you seek.  And where are the boundaries between regions 1 and 4 (for instance)?

Comment: @David G. Stork, The drawing has problem. Please pay attention to three axes X, Y and Z. The numbers must be attached to ZX and  ZY surfaces. Two others are: (X and Y:2\pi) and (X:2\pi and Y). I want to refer them but I decided to call them by numbers.

Comment: It is clear you are not a native English speaker.  Your question is quite unclear.  Please work directly with a native English speaker to write a clear statement of your problem.  Otherwise, we cannot help you.  What is line1?  plot1?